# How can I start writing IT article?

Tags: knowledge-management

I am new stack overflow user.

I see that I can post a new question by clicking 'question' button.

But if I need to share knowledge,e.g., write some 101 tutorial.

How can I start writing it?

Which menu or link should I go to to post my article?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: @Marc B  From your link, I cannot find any ttopic mention about writing an article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First [read](https://stackoverflow.com/help) help pointed by @Marc B comment.

Then, let´s suppose you have a answer to a common question and you want to share. You can ask the question and click the link to "Answer your own question". This way you will be sharing your knowledge.

However, please, keep your questions/answers in the scope of stackoverflow, ask good questions or your answers would end up being useless.

Comment: Thank you so much, but my question is stack overflow allow user to write some article like docker101, node101, or not without asking a question?

Comment: I don´t think this is the scope of stackoverflow right now. And if this is a suggestion it shall be submitted to meta

Comment: Thanks so much @JrBenuto